# Why do Han and Qi'ra lack ID chips?

Tags: star-wars, han-solo, solo-a-star-wars-story

Early in *Solo*, we find Han and Qi'ra attempting to bribe their way past an Imperial checkpoint using a vial of stolen coaxium because they do not have ID chips, which are required to pass. I'm not fully understanding why Han and Qi'ra can not simply sell the coaxium in order to get the funds necessary to get ID chips.

Why do Han and Qi'ra not have access to ID chips? Are these chips ordinary ID card-like things that essentially anyone can get at their local government office (whatever the Corellian equivalent to the DMV or passport office is), or are they restricted to only those that the Empire specifically wants to allow to travel?

Comment: If you think the line at American DMVs is bad, wait til you see the lines at the Corellian DMV!

Comment: Because selling the Coaxium runs the risk of being ripped off, having the info sold back to their boss and adds extra time to the plan.

Comment: @Valorum however, the same risk was present with respect to bribing the guard at the checkpoint. Han even acknowledges this - that he doesn't want to hand over the coaxium until *both* of them are through the gate.

Comment: I figured it would be more difficult (and perhaps more expensive) to find someone willing to forge or illicitly issue ID chips than to bribe the guard at the checkpoint.  And they were kind of in a hurry, IIRC.

Comment: Re: "I'm not fully understanding why Han and Qi'ra can not simply sell the coaxium in order to get the funds necessary to get ID chips": The movie gives the implication that there's really no time; their goal of getting offplanet has suddenly become much more urgent, because they're being actively chased by the people that Han stole the coaxium from.